# Как пишут драйвера на python

Tags: python-3.x, arduino

Добрый день Хотелось бы узнать как пишутся драйвера на языке python для Arduino ??
Множите привести пример

Answer (score 6):

Никак. Интерпретатор питона вы в контроллер AVR не засунете.

Более того, качественный драйвер должен работать в режиме ядра, и тащить туда четверть гига питоньего окружения смысла особого нет.

Драйверы пишут на C

Comment: 1- Про "четверть гига": посмотрите на micropython (работает на некоторых микроконтроллерах, хотя всё равно слишком толстый без дополнительной памяти для arduino). [micro:bit](http://python.microbit.org/editor.html) позволяет хоть в браузере на Питоне писать 2- PeachPy позволяет бинарники генерировать, встраивая x86-64 ассемблер в Питон (arduino другая архитектура, но идея ясна). 3- (не имеет отношения к драйверу) для тех случаев, когда arduino к другому компьютеру подключена, можно использовать Питон код чтобы команды посылать

Comment: были попытки и напрямую интерпретатор исполнять [PyMite](https://goo.gl/g7AaUw)